# How can I increase Emacs key repeat rate in OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: emacs, osx-mountain-lion

Emacs does not seem to respect the OS's key repeat rate.  I'm using emacs in the terminal.  I've set the repeat rate to as fast as possible by directly editing the settings in the following file (I restarted after making the change):

```
open ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
```

The rest of the system observes the repeat rate.  The terminal works as expected, as does vim.  But, when I use emacs I still get the annoyingly slow repeat rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running [Emacs 24](http://www.emacsformacosx.com) and it seems to use the same repeat rate as the terminal, but some of the packages I use slow it down. Try `emacs -q` (skipping your startup file) and then turn off font-lock-mode and see if it's any better. If it is, then it's Emacs being slow.

Comment: Yeah, skipping the startup file yielded a much faster response.  Enabling and disabling font-lock-mode did not cause a change in behavior.  I'm glad to know that the problem is not emacs but some bit of configuration.